# Pyqt5 layout button

Tags: python, pyqt5

i tried to put a button in the bottom and left place of my application, i'm using layout but it doesn't move button. here my code

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle("Pulsometer")

    self.setGeometry(0, 0, 960, 540)

    self.setFixedSize(QSize(960,540))
    self.setMinimumSize(QSize(960,540))
    self.setMaximumSize(QSize(1920,1080))


    self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(50,50,50);")

    self.title = QLabel("Pulsometer", self)
    font = QFont()
    font.setFamily('Montserrat')
    font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)
    self.title.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255,255,255);")
    font.setPointSize(30)
    self.title.setFont(font)
    self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.title)

    self.button = QPushButton("Press Me", self)
    self.button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(119,54,54); color: rgb(255,255,255);")
    self.button.setCheckable(True)
    self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.verticalLayout.addStretch()
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button, alignment=Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignBottom)
```

some suggestion?

Comment: `self.title.setLayout(self.verticalLayout)`

Comment: To clarify, adding widgets **to** a layout is not enough, that layout must be set **on** a widget . Be aware, anyway, using a QLabel as central widget is not really useful. You might prefer to add a basic QWidget, then set the layout on it, and add both the label *and* the button to that layout. I suggest you to study the documentation about [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and do some testing on your own, both from code and with [Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).